# Xubuntu 20.04 suddenly very slow

Tags: 20.04

Upgraded to 20.04 about a month ago.  The file manager opened slowly, browsers open slowly, etc.  Two days ago the system became intolerably slow.  How to reinstall Xubuntu 20.04?  The system just hung again for 15 seconds between typing "Xubuntu" and "20.04"  Sporadic hang up in every application I try to run such as Parole Media Player playing a file from disk and VLC hanging up so I had to kill it from the terminal.

Comment: Can you rule out hardware or disk failure by observation (noise, heat) or by running diagnostic tools?

Comment: What diagnostic tools?